# scrolling direction to change elements class dynamically in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to listen to the scrolling event of the page and according to the scrolling direction, it should be able to change css classes of elements. If scrolling happens for right/left, one css class should be added to an element and from another element that css class should be removed. if scrolling happens for down/up, above change should be happened in opposite way. My attempt is as below.

```
created() {
 window.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
},
destroyed() {
 window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
},
data() {
  return {
    isDisableScrollableForTable: false,
    isDisableScrollableForSub: false
  };
}
methods: {
 handleScroll(event) {
  $el.on("scroll", function() {
    // get current scroll position
    const currY = $el.scrollTop();
    const currX = $el.scrollLeft();

    // determine current scroll direction
    const currDir = {
      x:
        currX > lastPos.x ? "right" : currX === lastPos.x ? "none" : "left",
      y: currY > lastPos.y ? "down" : currY === lastPos.y ? "none" : "up"
    };

   
    if (currDir.x == "left" || currDir.x == "right") {
      this.isDisableScrollableForSub = true;
      this.isDisableScrollableForTable = false;
      
      console.log("horizontal scroll");
    } else if (currDir.y == "up" || currDir.y == "down") {
      this.isDisableScrollableForSub = false;
      this.isDisableScrollableForTable = true;
     
      console.log("vertical scroll");
    }
    // update last scroll position to current position
    lastPos.y = currY;
    lastPos.x = currX;
  });
 }
}
<div
  id="subScrolling"
  :class="{ isDisableScrollable: isDisableScrollableForSub }">
</div>
<div
  id="tableScrolling"
  :class="{ isDisableScrollable: isDisableScrollableForTable }">
</div>
```

Here scrolling direction could be identified correctly. But css classes were not bounded. Where I was get wrong and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve the `this` context:

```js
$el.on("scroll", () => {
...
})
```

Otherwise the callback function injects its own `this`

Comment: Also, what is `$el` referring to? It looks undefined. Whatever it is, you appear to be registering a callback function on it every time you scroll (because that's what `on` does). That's not what you want.  There should be no need to have both `on` and `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to do any action related to DOM, you must call in the mounted lifecycle. The second thing is that we should target the document element on which we want to listen. In my case, I have used ref prop to target the element and then in the mounted function, I started the listener and started to listen on the event.

Also, we don't need to use $el, as it's undefined and is not targeting anything in vue.js until you assign any element to it.

Let's not talk much and check the working code **example below**.

```
<template>
  <div ref="scrollContainer">
    <div
      id="subScrolling"
      :class="{ isDisableScrollable: isDisableScrollableForSub }">
    </div>
    <div
      id="tableScrolling"
      :class="{ isDisableScrollable: isDisableScrollableForTable }">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  mounted() {
    this.$refs.scrollContainer.addEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  destroyed() {
  this.$refs.scrollContainer.removeEventListener("scroll", this.handleScroll);
  },
  data() {
    return {
      isDisableScrollableForTable: false,
      isDisableScrollableForSub: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleScroll(event) {
        // get current scroll position
        const currY = event.target.scrollTop;
        const currX = event.target.scrollLeft;
        let lastPos = {x: 0, y: 0}
        // determine current scroll direction
        const currDir = {
          x:
            currX > lastPos.x ? "right" : currX === lastPos.x ? "none" : "left",
          y: currY > lastPos.y ? "down" : currY === lastPos.y ? "none" : "up"
        };

      
        if (currDir.x == "left" || currDir.x == "right") {
          this.isDisableScrollableForSub = true;
          this.isDisableScrollableForTable = false;
          
          console.log("horizontal scroll");
        } else if (currDir.y == "up" || currDir.y == "down") {
          this.isDisableScrollableForSub = false;
          this.isDisableScrollableForTable = true;
        
          console.log("vertical scroll");
        }
        // update last scroll position to current position
        lastPos.y = currY;
        lastPos.x = currX;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```